# Username login to Active Directory not correct

Tags: azure-active-directory, onedrive

I want access file in onedrive through console app. I follow this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-access-file-data/3-exercise-access-files-onedrive but i have a problem with Username login, i cant use my main email to login. Look pic below:
[image]

My email is 2 with full email is: closeheart777@live.com (which i cant use to login with). So i create the new user is number 3, i can use username: phong@closeheart777live.onmicrosoft.com to login. I think the problem is user principal name and username for my email is not actually email.

How i can use my main email to login?
Appreciate any comments.

Answer (score 1):

`@closeheart777live.onmicrosoft.com` is actually your default domain name.Our general email address is: username + domain name,`@closeheart777live.onmicrosoft.com` will be added to your username by default when you create a user or invite guest users.

[image]

If you want to log in using `closeheart777@live.com`, obviously you need to use `@live.com` as your domain name. You can set @live.com as your domain name by [custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain#:%7E:text=Search%20for%20and%20select%20Azure,Select%20Add%20domain.) name.

[image]

Comment: appreciate your answer. What is the username for my email if i dont change domain. 
is it ``closeheart777_live.com#EXT#@closeheart777live.onmicrosoft.com``? i already try to login by it but not work

Comment: @Paxton.Huynh  I think it should be: `closeheart777_live.com@closeheart777live.onmicrosoft.com`, did you set this extra `#EXT#` yourself? If your user type is `member`, it should not have `#EXT#`,it usually appears on `guest` users.

Comment: I do nothing, i already try username like your suggest but it return ``The user account does not exist...``

Comment: @Paxton.Huynh  A relatively simple method is to delete the original user, and then use `closeheart777_live.com` as the user name to re-create the user. Operate as `Figure 1` in my answer.

Comment: it not allow to delete the original user. I will try another way. thanks you for your help

Comment: @Paxton.Huynh  After my test, you should use `closeheart777@live.com` to log in. What error did you encounter when logging in?

Comment: it show ``Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (NotAcceptable).``. but when i use username ``phong@closeheart777live.onmicrosoft.com`` which i create, everything fine. little bit confused

Comment: my target is for everyone can upload, download file in my onedrive without required login. for instance, with google drive i did. for first time, it required me to login my google account, then it return credential, i store that credential on my server, so client just call api to down or upload file without login. Is there any way to archive that with one drive? i will change solution

Comment: thanks @Nishant-MSFTIdentity, i found solution for my problem, i call MS Graph Api for token and refresh token, store it on server and use web service for auto get new token base on refresh token